# chartjs dentro de for php

Tags: php, javascript, chart.js

tengo la siguiente duda, estoy comenzando en PHP JAVASCRIPT, tengo que según registros de la base de datos generar tantos gráficos como registros tenga, previo a esto estoy haciendo pruebas con un FOR dentro de PHP y pienso que puede ser así como coloco a continuación, no me muestra los gráficos si muestra el contador como se ve en el código:

archivo : graficos.php

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i;
 echo '<br>';
 echo '<div style="width: 40%">';
 echo '<canvas id="canvas'.$i.'"></canvas>';
 echo '</div>';
 
 echo '<script>';
 echo 'var barChartData'.$i.' = {';
    echo 'type: "bar",';
    echo 'data: {';
    echo '   labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],';
    echo '    datasets: [{';
    echo '        label: "n° de Votos",';
    echo '        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],';
    echo '        backgroundColor: [';
    echo '            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",';
    echo '            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",';
    echo '            "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",';
    echo '            "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",';
    echo '            "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",';
    echo '            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)"],';
    echo '        borderColor: [';
    echo '            "rgba(255,99,132,1)",';
    echo '            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",';
    echo '            "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",';
    echo '            "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",';
    echo '            "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",';
    echo '            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)"],';
    echo '        borderWidth: 1}]},options: {scales: {yAxes: [{ticks: {beginAtZero:true}}]}}}';
    
 echo 'window.onload = function(){';
    echo 'var ctx'.$i.' = document.getElementById("canvas'.$i.'").getContext("2d");';
    echo 'var mychart'.$i.' = new Chart(ctx'.$i.',barChartData'.$i.', {';
    echo '    responsive : true});';
 echo '}';
 echo '</script>'; 
 
 }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que el chart lo hagas en javascript en un archivo separado, en una funcion.  En PHP solo llamas la funcion y le pasas los parametros necesarios como los datos.

Comment: Bienvenido @felipe hidalgo, como dice @alanfcm, lo mejor para esos caso es separar las cosas , el javascript en un archivo `js`, despues solo llamas a la función para tener la data.

Comment: Ya voy a separar, veré como me va por cada vez que aumente el FOR en PHP ire por la funcion en JAVASCRIPT, esa seria la lógica a seguir cierto? lo que se me complico es que cada vez que en php  aumento el contador le pase el valor a la función

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi no es necesario tanto php:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {

$str = <<<EOF
    <br>
    <div style="width: 40%">
    <canvas id="canvas{$i}"></canvas>
    </div>
EOF;
echo $str;

}
?>

<script>

function barChartData(){
        let barChartData = {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
           labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "n° de Votos",
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
                    "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)"],
                borderColor: [
                    "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
                    "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
                    "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
                    "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
                    "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
                    "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)"],
                borderWidth: 1}]},options: {scales: {yAxes: [{ticks: {beginAtZero:true}}]}}}
        return barChartData;
}

window.onload = function(){
    document.querySelectorAll('canvas[id^="canvas"]').forEach((element,index)=>{
        let ctx= element.getContext("2d");
        let mychart = new Chart(ctx,barChartData(), {
        responsive : true});
    });
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esto es lo que necesitaba, es justo y preciso, la experiencia es lo que no tengo, muchas gracias Bryro

Comment: debes marcarla como respondida!

Comment: La marque con el TICK verde, ese es, cierto :) ?